# Find a string (like grep -q) within only a section of a file

Tags: shell, text-processing, grep, awk

I want to write some Bash that can verify that a string exists in a configuration file. I can't change the file format, it belongs to a different application.

The file is subdivided into groups named by strings in square brackets.

This should be a success:

```
[group1]
MyParameter
junk1
junk2

[group2]
junk3
junk4
```

This should be an error:

```
[group1]
junk1
junk2

[group2]
MyParameter
junk3
junk4
```

I can do a `grep -q` to verify that `MyParameter` exists in the file, but if it's located in some other group and not `group1`, then I'm still busted.

If `MyParameter` existed in both groups, I wouldn't care enough to flag an error, as long as it existed in `group1`.

I can't depend on line numbers (head, tail, etc). Also, I'd be happier if it was generic enough that it doesn't depend on the name of `group2` (the script would just know that if it found another line beginning and ending with square brackets, that terminates the previous group).

Comment: Is MyParameter alway immediately after [groupX] lines, or it does not have any specific position?

Comment: No specific position...

Comment: Ok, take a look at my answer, it should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever faced with a text processing problem, some people say “let's use awk”. More often than not, they have a solution.

```
awk '
    /^\[.*\]$/ {group = $0}
    group == "[group1]" && $1 == "MyParameter" {found=1; exit}
    END {exit !found}
'
```

Comment: Nice one. What it does (as explanation to the uninitiated): it remembers the last seen group name (the one in square brackets) while going through the file. And when it encounters the parameter together with the correct group it sets the flag `found` to 1. At the end it exits with the appropriate status code (0 if the param has been found in the correct group).

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `sed` you can do

```
sed -n '/\[group1\]/,/\[group2\]/{/MyParameter/p}' input-file
```

that will write `MyParameter` only when it is in the `group1` section. If the section after `group1` is not always `group2`, you can substitute `group2` with `.*`.

Comment: (+1) `/^MyParameter&/` will resolve an embedded pattern match (eg. MyParameters)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Perl script that should do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 group pattern [file...]\n" if scalar @ARGV < 2;

my $group = shift;
my $pattern = shift;

my $curr_group = undef;
my $matched = 0;
while (<>) {
    if (/^\[(.*)\]/) {
        $curr_group = $1;
    }
    else {
        if (defined $curr_group and 
            $curr_group eq $group and 
            /$pattern/) 
        {   
            print "Match\n";
            $matched = 1;
        }
    }
}

if (not $matched) {
    print "No match\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ `egrep 'MyParameter|^\[.*\]$' file.conf | head -2 | tail -1` == "MyParameter" ]
then 
  echo Success
else 
  echo Failure
fi
```

Comment: This works, when `[group1]` is the first group, otherwise it returns *Failure*.. I wonder if that was the question's intention ?

Comment: @fered Well we should ask to the question's author...